# Unexpected term after applying Stevin's law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, fluid-statics

Suppose we had a box with side $L$ and full of water up to height $H$ which can rotate with respect to segment $AB$.

If we wanted to find the force exerted by the water on the sides, since $dS=Ldz$, $dF=p(z)dS-p_0dS$ and by Stevin's law $p(z)=p_0+\rho gz$ (where $p_0$ is the pressure of the atmosphere around the box) we have that $dF=(p_0+\rho gz)Ldz-p_0Ldz=\rho gz LdS$ and by integrating from $0$ to $H$ we find $$\fbox{$F$}=\frac{1}{2}\rho gLH^2=\fbox{$\frac{1}{2}\rho g\frac{V^2}{L^3}$}$$ (where $V=HL^2$ is the volume occupied by the water).

Now, an answer I have seen for the same problem gives $$F=\underbrace{p_A\frac{V}{L}}_{?}+\frac{1}{2}\rho g\frac{V^2}{L^3}$$ where it seems there is an additional net pressure $p_A$ acting on the sides of the box.

**Where does this term come from?**

*By its form $p_A\frac{V}{L}=p_AHL$ it looks like there is some constant presurre $p_A$ acting on the sides of the box from the inside but I don't see where it comes from.*

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that the line (AB) is horizontal, and that the box has been rotated 45 degrees to a fixed position where the heavy line is  now horizontal?

Comment: @R.W.Bird if by heavy line you mean the rope which keeps the box from opening it is not horizontal.

Comment: Hello! I have taken the liberty to [resize your images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25051/) to improve readability. Feel free to rollback if you wish. Thanks!

Comment: So the box is horizontal and the axis or rotation is of no significance.

Comment: @R.W.Bird yes, correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"()=0+ (where 0 is the pressure of the atmosphere around the box)"
More to the point, $p_0$ is the pressure above the liquid, which therefore contributes to the pressure that the liquid itself exerts.

Near the beginning of your derivation you have subtracted $p_0$. I'm not sure why. The $p_A$ in the answer that you quote is simply the $p_0$ that you threw away!

[I have ignored your mention of rotation with respect to AB, since you don't refer to it again.]

Answer (score 1):

If you want the force exerted by the water, you must also include the (constant) pressure contributed by the atmosphere. This part of the force will be met by an equal force from the air outside of the wall.